# Is there a C++ implementation for scipy.fftpack.fftfreq?

Tags: python, c++

I would like to convert the following code into cpp from python.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.fftpack as fftpack

def fft_filter(video, freq_min, freq_max, fps):
    fft = fftpack.fft(video, axis=0)       
    print(video.shape)
    frequencies = fftpack.fftfreq(video.shape[0], d=1.0 / fps)
```

Is it possible to change these functions fftpack.fft() and fftpack.fftfreq() to cpp?

Comment: Sure it's possible. What have you tried? Do you have a C++ FFT implementation/library that you're using? That would be a good starting point

Comment: @alterigel for finding fft() i used Cimg library, but i don't know how to get fftfreq().

Comment: Have a look at [GitHub: scipy/scipy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/master/scipy/fft/_pocketfft) It seems that scipy.fft is based on pocketfft which is implemented in C++. As scipy is Open Source, you could transliterate yourself to C++ what's missing.